# How to validate CSV files lines, before importing them

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following flat file:

https://www.screencast.com/t/42mFZIrB04b

As you can see there is a ROW that is apparently not formatted correctly.

I have the following code:

```
 public class FlatFileModel
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string ArticleNumber { get; set; }
        public string ColorCode { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public string ActionPrice { get; set; }
        public string Delivery { get; set; }
        public string Q1 { get; set; }
        public string Size { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }




[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload()
        {
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                var httpPostedFileBase = Request.Files[0];
                if (httpPostedFileBase != null && httpPostedFileBase.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    //read data from input stream
                    using (var csvReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(httpPostedFileBase.InputStream))
                    {
                        string inputLine = "";

                        List<FlatFileModel> lineaArchivo = new  List<FlatFileModel>();
                        //read each line
                        while ((inputLine = csvReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            //get lines values
                            string[] values = inputLine.Split(new char[] { ',' });

                            for (int x = 0; x < values.Length; x++)
                            {
                                lineaArchivo.Add(new FlatFileModel()
                                {
                                    Key = values[0],
                                    ArticleNumber = values[1],
                                    ColorCode = values[2],
                                    Description = values[3],
                                    Price = values[4],
                                    ActionPrice = values[5],
                                    Delivery = values[6],
                                    Q1 = values[7],
                                    Size = values[8],
                                    Color = values[9]
                                });
                            }
                        }

                        csvReader.Close();
                    }
                }
                //var file = Request.Files[0];

                //if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                //{
                //    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                //    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/CSVs/"), fileName);
                //    file.SaveAs(path);
                //}
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

I need an easy way to detect the ROWS that wont fit into the format, so Ican just ignore them, or LOG them as error, but I am not sure how can I do that.

Thanks

Comment: For your case in particular, the number of elements in `string[] values` will be something other than 8. Why don't you put that in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since everything is a string, you can just check if there is the correct number of elements in the row that you actually read from it.

```
if (values.Length == 10) {
    // row ok, do your for-loop
}
```

Comment: easy enough, and its for a simple test so should be OK, for real life I would need to do more complex calidation like STLDeveloper suggests

Answer (score 1):

Regarding how to validate the data, one good way to do this is to consider what constitutes a valid row versus an invalid row and then codify these rules.

You could then use that to build a regex statement that identifies rows that do not fit the pattern.

For instance, you can check that each field matches an appropriate pattern (2nd column of each row should contain an integer, 5th column should contain a 2-place decimal value, 6th column should contain nothing, 9th column should contain an integer, etc.)